# Facing Issues in Multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading

I have written a code where it will launch the fixed number of threads from the main class. Below function is just a part of it . All threads will come to this method. I have given thread names like USER1, USER2 etc.

My requirement is that in this method after driver=WebDriver....... statement all of my threads should wait until they all get the driver. I know we can join . But unable to implement here . Can someone please guide

```
private  void testSuitLogin(String driverType){

        try{
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" Start Time "+System.currentTimeMillis());
            driver = WebDriverFactory.getDriver(driverType);
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" End Time "+System.currentTimeMillis());
            homePage();
            googleSignIn();
            driver.quit();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            if(driver==null)
            {
                totalNumberOfUsers--;
                return ;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: So, you have to block until some event occurs?  Why not use a lock of some kind? Have a look at [Lock Objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/newlocks.html)

Comment: I think you'll need another class to supervise your Threads. They should register themselves to this class (checkin), then checkout and fall asleep with Thread.sleep(). And as soon as all the threads have checkout, notify them all to wake them up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `CountDownLatch`. Create a `CountDownLatch` with a `fixed number of thread` value and call `countdown()` after you get the instance of the `WebDriver` and then call `await()` to wait until all the threads arrive there.

```
CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(fixedNumber);

private  void testSuitLogin(String driverType){

  try{
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" Start Time "+System.currentTimeMillis());
    driver = WebDriverFactory.getDriver(driverType);
    countDownLatch.countDown();  // decreases the value of latch by 1 in each call.
    countDownLatch.await();      //It will wait until value of the latch reaches zero.
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" End Time "+System.currentTimeMillis());
    homePage();
    googleSignIn();
    driver.quit();
  }
  catch(Exception e){
    if(driver==null)
    {
      countDownLatch.countDown();
      totalNumberOfUsers--;
      return ;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This will deadlock when a driver call fails.

Comment: One should in case of specific exception decrement the `countDownLatch` in `catch` block

Comment: Waiting for all to get driver, would be meaningless if you just continue when one has failed. Aborting application seems more reasonable. But OP has given no indication what should be done, so leaving that to them. But yes, the catch is a good place to handle that situation.

Comment: @AadityaGavandalkar Thanks for suggestion and Edit.

Answer (score 0):

First: If all wait for all to get the driver, then you have a problem when one fails to get the driver.

In order to have all wait for each other (I don't think I have actually ever done that, but here is a suggestion). Since you know the number of threads, you can make something like:

- Thread gets driver
- Thread calls a synchronized method (only 1 thread can run it at a time) that decrements a counter by 1 (initialized to the number of threads).
- Thread yields.
- Thread runs again, calls a method that checks if the counter has reached 0.
- A: Counter is not 0 yet, thread yields.
- B: Counter is 0, thread continues its work.